# Access Java REST WebServices in HTML pages with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, web-services, rest

I have a big problem with RESTFul webservices.

Here is my architecture :

- Server-side : I use EJB3 + RESTFul webservices.
- Client-side : I use bootstrap twitter + JQuery 1.8 and Ajax methods to access my webservices.

I created a JSP on server-side to test my webservice before commiting it for client-side developpers. When I use this JSP all my webservices are working perfectly !
Then I try to access these webservices from an html page (remotely) and my `$.ajax` request doesn't work.

I rode a lot of posts about that, some people speaks about JSONP adding `callback=?` at the end of the URL or using `dataType='jsonp'`

The best I can do is seeing the object in my browser Resources but only error callback is called. 
I have an error like : `ParserError : Error: jQuery18207595316471997648_1348928429983 was not called.`

When I try to use `dataType='text json'` (as mentioned in some posts) nothing happens but the error callback is still called !

The thing is that when I just put the GET url directly in my web browser I can see the string of the corresponding JSON object, so it doesn't seems to come from my webservices.

here is an example of this JSON string :

```
{"member1":[{"email":"romain@gmail.com","firstname":"Romain","idMember":"4","lastname":"Dev","login":"romain","password":"5026bc63b5418ffdb54f238db245ec01"},{"email":"productowner@gmail.com","firstname":"Product","idMember":"7","lastname":"Owner","login":"prodowner","password":"f5bf48aa40cad7891eb709fcf1fde128"}]}
```

Here is an example of my ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost:8080/myresource/all',
    type:'GET',     
    success: function(reponse) {        
        renderList(reponse);
    },  
    error:function (xhr, status, error){        
        alert('Error :'+xhr.responseText+' ('+status+' - '+error+')');  
    },  
    dataType: 'json'

  });
```

I use Glassfish server 3.1.2 and the only log I can see is :

```
INFO: Couldn't find JAX-B element for class javax.ws.rs.core.Response
```

But why would it work in my JSP and not in my HTML pages ??

I'm really stuck, I really need your help ! :)

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function :

```
function sendRequest(success_callback,failure_callback,data,ws_url,asynchronous){
$.ajax({ 
    async: asynchronous,
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,//if cross domain req 
    dataType: "json",
    Accept : "application/json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url:"url",
    data:  data,
    success:success_callback,
    error: failure_callback
});
```

}

```
function success_callback(msg){
```

}

```
function failure_callback(msg){
```

}